# ScriptJs: How to access variable after dynamically loading script?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, paypal, angular7

I'm using [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js) to dynamically load the Paypal client-side buttons as part of an Angular7 `PaypalPaymentController`. My component's code looks as follows:

```
import {Configuration, Procedure} from '../models';
import {get } from 'scriptjs';

@Component({
   ...
})
export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() configuration: Configuration;
  @Input() procedure: Procedure;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    get(`https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${this.configuration.paypalClientId}&currency=${this.configuration.currency}`, () => {
      paypal.Buttons({  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< compiler error here
        // set up the transaction
        createOrder: this.createOrder,
        // finalize the transaction
        onApprove: this.onApprove
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    });
  }

  ...
}
```

After executing `scriptjs`'s `get` how do I access the `paypal` variable defined within the dynamically loaded script? I get a TS compiler error otherwise ...

`ERROR in src/app/payment/payment.component.ts(24,7): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'paypal'.`

**UPDATE:** the complete Paypal client-side example is the following (copy-pasted from there):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <!-- Add meta tags for mobile and IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD"></script>

    <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({

            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: '0.01'
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },

            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                });
            }


        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding the following line after the imports:

```
declare let paypal: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how you setup your environment. I guess you have to import [PayPal rest sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paypal-rest-sdk) as well. For typescript there are [@types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/paypal-rest-sdk) too.

Comment: Thanks! The URL in the dynamic `get` call is the importing of the Paypal SDK.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice. Anyway, the ts compiler won't know about `paypal`. The @types could help.